How to get right side-by-side linguistic examples?
I am trying to use package expex to create two linguistics examples side by side. For the B example, I don't know how to make 're' appear in the first line, which keeps appearing in the third line. Could anyone let me how to adjust the position of 're' in the B example. Here's the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
%packages for examples
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{
    aboveglftskip = -.05cm,
    aboveexskip = 2 pt,
    belowexskip = 2 pt,
    belowpreambleskip = 0 pt,
    extraglskip = 0 pt,
    everygla=,
    interpartskip= 0 pt
    %   numoffset=\parindent

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\ex[glhangstyle=none, glwidth=2.5in]<@period>
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth} % Adjusted width
A: \quad
\begingl
\gla BJ jintian you 35-du.//
\glb BJ today have 35-$^\circ C$//
\glft `It's $35^\circ C$ in BJ today.'//
\endgl
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth} % Adjusted width
B: \quad
\begingl
\gla bu, BJ jintian bi \textbf{35-du} \nogloss{*(} @ \textbf{hai}) re.//
\glb NEG BJ today BI 35-$^\circ C$ even hot//
\glft `No, BJ is hotter than $35^\circ C$ today.'//
\endgl
\end{minipage}
\xe
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for adding an example document to your question!

You need to set the glwidth to \textwidth and then adjust the size of the minipages accordingly.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
%packages for examples
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{
    aboveglftskip = -.05cm,
    aboveexskip = 2 pt,
    belowexskip = 2 pt,
    belowpreambleskip = 0 pt,
    extraglskip = 0 pt,
    everygla=,
    interpartskip= 0 pt
    %   numoffset=\parindent
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}
\ex[glhangstyle=none, glwidth=\textwidth]<@period>
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth} % Adjusted width
A: \quad
\begingl
\gla BJ jintian you 35-du.//
\glb BJ today have 35-$^\circ C$//
\glft `It's $35^\circ C$ in BJ today.'//
\endgl
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth} % Adjusted width
B: \quad
\begingl
\gla bu, BJ jintian bi \textbf{35-du} \nogloss{*(} @ \textbf{hai}) re.//
\glb NEG BJ today BI 35-$^\circ C$ even hot//
\glft `No, BJ is hotter than $35^\circ C$ today.'//
\endgl
\end{minipage}
\xe
\end{document}



Thanks a lot, that actually works! really appreciate it!

Alan sometimes back you had a link for resources for linguistics, is this still available?

@yannisl Not quite sure what you're referring to. Perhaps this: https://www.adamliter.org/content/LaTeX/latex-workshop-for-linguists.pdf made by a former student?

Thanks. Yes that is the one.
